# How to select various Task Continuation strategies in TPL

Tags: c#-4.0, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

Consider the following continuation:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
{
    MethodA();
})
.ContinueWith((t)=>
{
    MethodB();
})
.ContinueWith((t)=>
{
    MethodC();
});
```

As I know the execution will be like this:

1. `MethodA` executes.
2. `MethodB` executes after `MethodA` completes.
3. `MethodC` executes after `MethodB` completes.

What if I wanted the `MethodC` to continue after `MethodA` completes.(instead of waiting for `MethodB`)

I'm looking for a solution other than manually declaring the task variables, instead I want to use the method sequencing by the fluent factory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start another tasks for `MethodB` and `MethodC` so that they execute in parallel once `MethodA` completes:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
{
    MethodA();
})
.ContinueWith((t)=>
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        MethodB();
    });

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        MethodC();
    });
});
```